# WTForms with a variable amount of textareas

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a HTML form with my Flask application which includes a textarea however, the user can press a button which adds another textarea to the form to create an infinite amount of textareas.

As I'm not using WTForms, validation is much harder and so I've done it on the client side with Javascript however anyone with programming skills can edit this code which is unsafe. I would prefer to validate the form with WTForms.

Is this even possible to do with WTForms and Flask or would I have to create my own method with Flask and flashing messages to validate the form? Thanks.

**Edit:**

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="add()">Add textarea</button>

<script>
  function add() {
    var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(textarea);
  }
</script>
```

So in my case, I also have an input at the beginning which I would like to validate. I would also like to validate that all the textareas so that they are not allowed to be empty.

I would like to validate this with WTForms though to create a form with WTForms, it must be created in Python and then rendered in HTML. As textareas are added to the form, they cannot be validated as they are not defined in the python code to create the WTForms.

The issue is, I would like to be able to add form elements to a form created with WTForms.

Comment: I think the answer is yes it is possible, but I am not sure I understand your concerns with validation. Have you used WTForms? I can see a way to add text areas as a result of a button click. You could use the `validate_on_submit()` function which is a part of WTForms as a trigger for adding a new text area. If this stuff is new to you, I can try writing up an answer. I am new to Flask as well though, so my answer will likely not be technically correct.

Comment: How would I go about this then? Because as far as I know, with WTForms I have to specify the form and it's textareas in Python before it is rendered in HTML.

Comment: I have yet to start actually writing code for this, which I plan to do regardless of whether or not an answer shows up, for my own learning purposes. I think if you declare a global dictionary in Python, you could communicate the button click to the Python script, and with proper control send off a new text area to be rendered, once re-directed. You might not need a global dictionary... but the arguments to render_template would need to be generated within the view function. That's how I am seeing it. I am sure though that there is an extension with this in mind.

Comment: I have no issue with adding a textarea to the page, I'm doing that with javascript, however it is just getting these new textareas to work with WTForms.

Comment: Can you show some of the code? i.e. The relevant parts of your flask app and the project directory structure. I'm not understanding your problem for some reason, I think seeing some code will help me understand what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87668/discussion-between-skywalker-and-pav-sidhu).

Comment: Alright here is what I have thus far. [flasky-buttons](https://github.com/callmeskywalker/flasky-buttons). `git clone` it and make sure you all the extensions I import at the top of `buttons.py`. Run `python buttons.py` and then visit `http://localhost:5000/buttons`. I provide the same functionality of adding buttons via WTForms. I don't know what you want the submit button to do, store the data from all the fields? Hope this helps, let me know of any troubles. I will write up my answer once I have the submit button functioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by using WTForms to validate the `<input type=text>` and then using simple `flash()` messages for the textareas if they were empty.

```
@app.route('/form')
def form():
  form = some_form()

  if request.method == 'POST':
        newQuestions = []
        i = 1
        alreadyBlank = False
        while True:
            try:
                question = request.form['question' + str(i)]

                if question.strip(' \t\n\r') == '' and not alreadyBlank
                    flash('Please don\'t leave any questions blank.')
                    alreadyBlank = True

                newQuestions.append(question)
                i += 1
            except:
                break

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    input_content = form.input.data
```